# Windows Phone 8 region-neutral resource file from external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, localization

I have Windows Phone 8 App project and Portable Library project with resources to be used in Phone App. It's developed in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

I try to use region-neutral resource files (e.g. AppResources.en.resx instead of AppResources.en-GB.resx).

If I place region-neutral resource files in Phone App Project everything works fine.

If I place resource files in Portable Library project the only default resource file is used by application.

If I use region-specific naming (AppResources.en-GB.resx) for resources files in Portable Library Project everything is OK too.

Class to access resources:

```
public class LocalizedStrings
{
    private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources();

    public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }
}
```

Reference to class in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <res:LocalizedStrings xmlns:res="clr-namespace:Project.Phone.App;assembly=Project.Phone.App" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Example above is for resources located in Phone App Project. "Project.Phone.App" is changed to "Project.Library.LocalizedResources" in case when resources are located in Portable Library Project.

Usage:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
```

Comment: The question is "How to define region-neutral resources in Portable Library?"